# Are Tesla cars hacker-safe?

Tags: penetration-test

I was wondering, what would happen if a Tesla car was hacked into?

Are future cars designed to be able to be stopped by police via remote access and commands? What if someone actually causes an accident using this method? Who will be to blame? How can one prove the accident wouldn't be caused by the police or someone (connecting to say a SIM card embedded in the car)?

Comment: LEOs have compelled onstar to perform actions on their behalf.

Comment: @AndréBorie: https://www.onstar.com/us/en/services/security.html, http://enterthezone.net/onstar/?p=283, http://www.nytimes.com/2003/12/21/automobiles/21SNOOP.html, http://www.metnews.com/articles/comp111903.htm, yada yada

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you been reading the [news](https://www.wired.com/2015/07/hackers-remotely-kill-jeep-highway/).

Remote accesses are totally possibly especially as the IoT paradigm comes to surface.

As for who to blame for accidents caused by "smart cars", there are already feathers being ruffled. Lawmakers are grappling over this new reality as to who is to be held accountable in case of an accident where there is no human driver involved. An interesting pick is [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/05/14/upshot/when-driverless-cars-break-the-law.html)

Answer (score 6):

> I was wondering, what would happen if a Tesla car was hacked into?

Nothing good I can promise you that.

> Are future cars designed to be able to be stopped by police via remote access and commands?

Not that we know of.

> What if someone actually causes an accident using this method? Who will be to blame? How can one prove the accident wouldn't be caused by the police or someone (connecting to say a SIM card embedded in the car)?

I will assume you will not be able to blame anyone until after an investigation is complete and there was evidence that either the car was hacked into or not.

**Note:**
Hackers have already proven they can hack into a Tesla car. See [here](https://www.wired.com/2015/08/researchers-hacked-model-s-teslas-already/).